# How to get files stored on cloud debugging devices

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Huawei has a tool for testing apps online. My question is how to get the logs saved on device before the device is released and reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Huawei drive to get the files for download. Steps are

1. log in to Huawei ID, enable cloud storage
2. Use the device file browser to find the log file to be saved. Normally, this is stored under /sdcard/Android/data/{your package}/Log
3. Select and Share the file to Huawei Drive
4. Access the file from PC using http://cloud.huawei.com